# syntax error expected end of input but got keyword CREATE Google Cloud BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, linear-regression

```
SELECT * FROM `helpdesk.issues` LIMIT 1000

CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `helpdesk.predict_eta_v0` 
OPTIONS(model_type='linear_reg') AS
SELECT
 category,
 resolutiontime as label
FROM
  `helpdesk.issues`
```

Hi, the codes above are for trying to compose a new query for a tutorial that I am doing. I am getting syntax error for the Create keyword "syntax error expected end of input but got keyword CREATE" and I do not know how to solve it even seeing other people do it.
Please help and here is the link for the tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-dialogflow-bqml/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of first line

```sql
SELECT * FROM `helpdesk.issues` LIMIT 1000;
                                          ^
                                          |
                                         here
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the referenced tutorial - you should execute those queries one by one as a separate queries. so after you run first one - you supposed to clear the Query editor and copy paste (and then run) the second query and so on!  As an option - you can have both (or more) queries in the same editor - but run them separately by selecting one and instead of clicking `Run` button - click on `Run selected`

[image]

Obviously, if you wish you can copy paste and run all queries at once - but in this case you need to make sure they all separated by semicolon so it is treated as scripting - but, again, it is not how that tutorial is meant to be treated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `helpdesk.issues` LIMIT 1000;
    
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL
  `helpdesk.predict_eta_v0` OPTIONS(model_type='linear_reg') AS
SELECT
  category,
  resolutiontime AS label
FROM
  `helpdesk.issues`;
```